# How can I convert any normal font into dotted style font?

Tags: fonts

I want to develop Hindi and Marathi language worksheet for students. Therefor I needed a flexible font which can be easily changed as per requirement of text. This link contains [Shivaji](http://www.angelfire.com/pop/top4/fonts/shivaji.zip) font which is a normal font and I want to convert it into dotted style font. How to do this? Or if there is currently no easy drag and drop solution available, which kind of software and skill is required to do so?

Comment: What do you mean by 'dotted style font'? Can you provide an example?

Comment: @gronostaj dotted fonts are specially use for kinds to develop their handwriting skill. Here is some dotted fonts in English https://www.1001freefonts.com/dotted-fonts.php. Hindi i.e. Devanagari script also have that kind of fonts. But I want convert present font dotted form.

Comment: @gronostaj Dotted style means use a Normal font like dotted font. ex. Times new Roman is a Normal regular font we can use this font in Bold or italic style. Same thing I want that means Dotted style OR create or convert that same font into new dotted font.

Comment: @MadhavNikam, I wonder if you were able to find a solution because I need the same :)